# What does passing params in a jQuery plugin mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I've seen quite a lot of plugins which include objects like document, window, undefined into the arguments of both opening and closing.

Is this necessary? 
What does it mean? 
When should these be used?

```
;(function( $ , document, window, undefined) {
        "use strict";        

      $.fn.pluginname= function(options) {      

        //Code

      };
    })( jQuery, document, window, undefined);
```

Comment: Generally it just makes minifying the code more effective. passing jQuery to it allows the plugin to use `$` regardless of whether or not another library has taken control of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [jqueryboilerplate.com](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/)

```
 // undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
 // mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
 // passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
 // can no longer be modified.

 // window and document are passed through as local variable rather than global
 // as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
 // minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).
```

Fore some extra credit, follow the link and you will see why the method signature is prefaced with a semi-colon.

Also, your example is a bit incorrect: you should not be passing in 'undefined' on the last line when you invoke the function. The reasoning is explained in the first paragraph I pasted in above.